# Uploading files with HTML form via "Uppy"

Tags: javascript, html, forms, upload

[Uppy](https://uppy.io), a great javascript file upload [library](https://uppy.io/docs/form/) but I was unable to upload images with HTML form.

*Javascript Code:*

```
 var uppy = Uppy.Core();
 uppy.use(Form, {
   target: '#upload',
   getMetaFromForm: true,
   addResultToForm: true,
   resultName: 'uppyResult',
   triggerUploadOnSubmit: false,
   submitOnSuccess: false
 });
```

*HTML Code:*

```
<form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Images Upload</label>
    <div id="upload">
    </div>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

on J[SFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/emresaracoglu/ef3h5j0t/)

The upload area does not appear. What could be the reason?

Answer (score 1):

Starting the debugger, it shows that **Form** in 
`uppy.use(Form,`         is unkown or not declared.you should examine the examples(https://uppy.io/examples/xhrupload/ ) on uppy.io a little better by using the web developer tools of your browser. you should it also when encountering problems on you website.

Comment: I am not receiving any error messages on the console. No results

Answer (score 1):

Try This

1- HTML
Note: input name is a factor to get the input value

```
 <form id="formDataExample">
                    <input name="uppyResult" type="hidden">
                    <input name="folderId" id="folderId" type="hidden">

                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <div id="drag-drop-area"></div>

                    </div>
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <a data-bs-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
                            Additional Info
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="collapse" id="collapseExample">
                        <div class="card card-body">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <div class="mb-3">
                                        <label class="form-label">Title</label>
                                        <input type="text" name="title" class="form-control" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6">

                                    <div class="mb-3">
                                        <label class="form-label">Description</label>
                                        <input type="text" name="description" class="form-control" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <div class="mb-3">
                                        <label class="form-label">Source Info</label>
                                        <input type="text" name="sourceInfo" class="form-control" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6">

                                    <div class="mb-3">
                                        <label class="form-label">Comments</label>
                                        <input type="text" name="comments" class="form-control" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <div class="mb-3">
                                        <label class="form-label">Author</label>
                                        <input type="text" name="author" class="form-control" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6">

                                    <div class="mb-3">
                                        <label class="form-label">Language</label>
                                        <input type="text" name="language" class="form-control" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Upload</button>
                </form>
```

2- JS:

```
 <script>
        window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        'use strict';

        var uppy = new Uppy.Core({
            debug: true,
            autoProceed: false,
            //  meta: {
            //  userName: 'John',
            //folderId: `1`,
            //},
            locale: Uppy.locales.ru_RU
        });

        uppy.use(Uppy.Dashboard, {
            inline: true,
            target: '#drag-drop-area',
            showProgressDetails: true,
            note: '@T["input-library-file-uppy-note"]',
            height: 470,
            //metaFields: [
            //  { id: 'Title', name: 'Title', placeholder: 'file Title' },
            //  { id: 'description', name: 'description', placeholder: 'describe what the image is about' }
            //  { id: 'sourceInfo', name: 'sourceInfo', placeholder: 'sourceInfo' }
            //  { id: 'comments', name: 'comments', placeholder: 'comments' }
            //  { id: 'author', name: 'author', placeholder: 'author' }
            //  { id: 'language', name: 'language', placeholder: 'language' }
            //],
            browserBackButtonClose: false,
            hideUploadButton: true
        }).use(Uppy.XHRUpload, {
            endpoint: '/admin/library/upload-folder/',
            formData: true,
            fieldName: 'files[]',
        });

        uppy.use(Uppy.Form, {
            target: '#formDataExample',
            resultName: 'uppyResult',
            getMetaFromForm: true,
            addResultToForm: true,
            submitOnSuccess: false,
            triggerUploadOnSubmit: true,
        });

        window.uppy = uppy;


    });


</script>
```

3- Backend API

public async Task uploadFile(HttpContext context)
{

```
        if (context.Request.Form.Files.Any())
        {
            var file = new FileInput(context.Request.Form);

            return Results.Ok();
        }
        else
            return Results.BadRequest("at least one file is needed");
```

}

4- Mapping FileInput

```
public class FileInput
```

{

```
public string? FolderId { get; set; }
public string? Title { get; set; }
public string? Description { get; set; }
public string? SourceInfo { get; set; }
public string? Comments { get; set; }
public string? Author { get; set; }
public string? FileStreamId { get; set; }
public IFormFile File { get; set; }
public byte[] FileBytes { get; set; }
public string? Language { get; set; }

public FileInput()
{
}
public FileInput(IFormCollection form)
{
    FolderId = form.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == "folderId").Value;
    Title = form.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == "title").Value;
    Description = form.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == "description").Value;
    SourceInfo = form.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == "sourceInfo").Value;
    Comments = form.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == "comments").Value;
    Author = form.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == "author").Value;
    Language = form.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == "language").Value;
    File = form.Files[0];
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        File.CopyTo(ms);
        FileBytes = ms.ToArray();
    }
}
```

}

you will need to use those reference links

```
<script src="https://releases.transloadit.com/uppy/v2.12.3/uppy.min.js" type="module"></script>
<script src="https://releases.transloadit.com/uppy/v2.12.3/uppy.legacy.min.js" nomodule></script>
<script src="https://releases.transloadit.com/uppy/locales/v2.1.1/ru_RU.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: this really helped in figuring out the combination of dashboard to form controls, thanks

Comment: @WhatTheWhat
 you are right, thanks, but i think the form controls needs more work because the sample shows only the free text controls.